# linq performance: linq vs t-sql -- where does the time go?

Tags: sql, linq, performance

I am testing the Linq performance now and I cannot figure out what for some time is wasted (MS-SQL Server 2005).

So here is what I have: single table with clustered and non-clustered indices, all searches are done using columns which are covered in 100% by non-clustered index. I have 10 000 records, and all operations "touches" all records one by one. And now the times:

**T-SQL:**

- checking if each record exists (IF EXISTS...); yes, it exists -- 0:30 (30 seconds)
- updating each record -- 1:16

**LINQ:**

- fetching single records (SingleOrDefault) -- 5:58
- updating each record (it contains the fetching part) -- 9:34

Ok, checking for existence is not actually equivalent Linq and T-SQL but what really bothers me is the fact:

```
LINQ(fetch)+TSQL(update) < LINQ(update)
```

Also note that real update part is faster than fetching alone!

The updating in LINQ is already optimized to use primary (clustered) index not entire table (WHERE clause).

So, where did 2 minutes go?

**EDIT**

*When answering please answer the question why is such difference between LINQ and TSQL. Please do not discuss subject like: TSQL is for sets, you should do it in a batch (all records in once), you should make TSQL faster. Thank you.*

**edit2:**

The structure of the table is pretty easy:
id (PK), Name (int, external index), bit field + 40 fields or something like this

To focus on specific query I run such loop:

```
declare @i int;
declare @nr int;
declare @p1 bit;
declare @p0 int;

set @i = 0;
set @nr = 1000000000;

while @i<10000
begin
  select @p0=id,@p1=bit_field from test_mono where name=@nr;
  set @p1 = 1- @p1;
  update test_mono set bit_field=@p1 where id=@p0;
  set @i = @i+1;
  set @nr = @nr-1;
end
```

A little comment to that: bit_field here serves me as assurance that something will be modifier for sure. Counters which go up and down are from real data, I had to make sure with each select I get one record. And the last one -- with LINQ the only difference is SELECT, I fetch all fields (UPDATE is copied&pasted). However I can take time of LINQ SELECT and add it to this time (of TSQL) and I should get LINQ SELECT+UPDATE. But I don't get such time.

With previous edit I described a bit different structure, the reason is I try to make this as clear as possible. I don't like the examples of seriously real cases myself, so I'll try to make things easy for readers ;-)

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL generated by LINQ (using DataContext.Log) and then tried running the query analyser on that?

Comment: I assume by Linq you really mean Linq to SQL?

Comment: overhead, LINQ must access the database using the same SQL commands that you can run standalone. add a fraction of a second to 10,000 operations, and it adds up

Comment: Couple quick points - I would like to understand what it means by touches all records one by one. TSQL is a SET based paradigm and the best performance comes when embracing that and not the procedural mentalities that we coders are used to. Second, and this is a generalization, but I would be carry a pitchfork over to my DBAs office right now because 10,000 records is nothing in the database world. Especially if indexed properly those lookups should be sub 1 second.

Comment: @keithwarren7, based on the OPs question, it looks like they are looping over each of the 10,000 rows, one at a time.  this is quite slow, using LINQ or not.

Comment: I'm with keithwarren, I would never allow code like that in my production databases. If you can't update 10,000 little piddly records in less than 1 second, you have bad code in both methods.

Comment: @Jon, yes I looked at them. They are just standard SELECT, UPDATE queries. I checked those for execution plan, and indices were properly used.

Comment: @KM, Yes this is correct -- it is done one by one ON _PURPOSE_. @keithwarren7 and @HLGEM with all due respect PLEASE stick to the question. I am comparing performance for real cases -- I cannot tell customer, "hey buy 1000 books because you know my DB is optimized for sets". In my case I will get thousands of single updates. I cannot change it and please do not discuss this further, it goes nowhere.

Comment: @macias: So when you run the generated query directly, how long does it take?

Comment: @Jon, you mean copied&pasted query? I will add this as edit. I look at this gap I mentioned -- LINQ(SELECT)+TSQL(UPDATE) should give me LINQ(UPDATE) (linq update is really select+update). Or be close to it.

Comment: Use the SQL Profiler and see what your LINQ code is actually getting turned into SQL-wise.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, you mean SQL counterpart of LINQ? I did, it is normal SQL without any tricks or overhead.

Comment: No, I mean 1) post the Client Code with LINQ, 2) Use SQL profiler to capture and then Post the SQL Code actually executed for the LINQ code, 3) post the client code time, and finally 4) post what the profiler says is the actual execution time for the Client-LINQ generated SQL.  Then we can compare that to (among other things) what you are getting when you execute just the SQL separately.  We need the actual details here to do any real performance analysis.  The execution plans would be even better, but SO sucks wrt attached files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might start by using a tool such as [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to see what the actual SQL queries are being executed by LINQ.

Personally though, I've seen this time and time again, thus I tend when performance is the top priority I stay with TSQL.

More than likely the generated SQL has some oddities in it.  We would need to get more information though on the nature of your queries to get an idea of what you might be working with.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I tried it, but I don't see anything special about it. I can dump LINQ->SQL by myself, it does not show sql execution plan, so it's capabilities are rather limited (comparing to LINQ code + log).